Why does my Flaskform Run twice and doesnt pass through the right data?
I have a flask-form called "RegistreerForm" witch is in the directory "/registreren":
@app.route('/registreren', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registreren():
  Registreer_Form = RegistreerForm()
  return render_template("registreren.html", registerForm=Registreer_Form, gebruikers=Gebruikers.query.all())

this is the form inside "registreren.html":
  <form action="/code" method="POST">
    {{ registerForm.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ registerForm.First_Name.label }}
    {{ registerForm.First_Name() }}
    {{ registerForm.Last_Name.label }}
    {{ registerForm.Last_Name() }}
    {{ registerForm.Email_Adress.label }}
    {{ registerForm.Email_Adress() }}
    {{ registerForm.Password.label }}
    {{ registerForm.Password() }}
    {{ registerForm.Registreer_Knop() }}
  </form>

I want to send the data of the form to the directory "/code"
this is my /code flask script:
@app.route('/code', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def code():
 Registreer_Form = RegistreerForm()
 Code_Form = CodeForm()
 Firstname = Registreer_Form.First_Name.data
 Lastname = Registreer_Form.Last_Name.data
 Email = Registreer_Form.Email_Adress.data
 password = Registreer_Form.Password.data
 Code = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
 print(Firstname, Lastname, Email, password)
 print(Code)
 msg = Message(subject='Uw account',
               sender='informaticawebsitereplit@gmail.com',
               recipients=[Email])
 msg.body = f"Bedankt voor het aanmaken van uw account, {Firstname} \n\n Dit is uw code: {Code}"
 mail.send(msg)

 return render_template("code.html", CodeForm=Code_Form, registerForm=Registreer_Form, gebruikers=Gebruikers.query.all())

im using flask mail to send a mail using the data from the form, but when i run it, it automatically runs twice where the first time it works, but the second time it sets the form variables to None.
This is the eror i get:
Lukas Tori lukastori@gmail.com asdf
9068547
test
None None None None
9281527
test
[2024-04-07 17:41:13,544] ERROR in app: Exception on /code [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/main.py", line 201, in code
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
    message.send(connection)
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
    connection.send(self)
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 189, in send
    list(sanitize_addresses(message.send_to)),
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 125, in <lambda>
    return map(lambda e: sanitize_address(e, encoding), addresses)
  File "/home/runner/Eindopdracht-FlaskVwo/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 105, in sanitize_address
    nm, addr = addr
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

As you can see it runs twice, but the first time it prints the variables right but the second time the variables are None

As you can see from the log entry, the second call is of type GET. There is no suitable call visible in the code published here. So the question arises as to why you enable this request type in the route and where the underlying call comes from.
